# Stackoverflow wmd load on click event

Tags: stack-overflow, wmd, wmd-editor

I'm having a problem using the wmd re-engineer script.

The problem is the div where the wmd-container sits has `display:none`. This causes the following errors to be outputed constantly:

```
Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMNSHTMLTextAreaElement.selectionStart]
```

[Break On This Error] if (inputArea.selectionStart || inputArea.selectionStart === 0) {

If I add `display:none` on the `textarea` the problem goes away. But when I apply `display:block` on the elements; wmd buttons do not appear.

I am trying to figure out a way on how I can create an instance of this when the button is clicked.

Has anyone done this? I've had no luck =(

Comment: So I revisited the problem. I did this earlier and for some reason it was not working but now it does. Adding `display:none` on the div + the textarea. Click event changes display to block on both elements. Seems to be working now.